# how to make an application to run from a command in terminal

Tags: command-line

I downloaded `cool-retro-term` and put it in `/home/crs/cool-retro-term/` and I copied the `cool-retro-term.desktop` to `/usr/share/applications/`.

I used `sudo nano cool-retro-term.desktop` to modify the `EXEC` to `/home/crs/cool-retro-term/cool-retro-term`.

I don't know what to run in the terminal, maybe `cool-retro-term` or `sudo cool-retro-term -h` to open the application.

What are the steps? (I am a beginner)

Comment: Did you download the source? If so have you compiled it yet as described [here](https://github.com/Swordfish90/cool-retro-term)? You might also need to make the program executable with `chmod +x /home/crs/cool-retro-term/cool-retro-term`.

Comment: yes, i did everything like there and i ran alson the command you told me

Comment: As @Bernd mentioned below, you can't execute the script using `cool-retro-term` from anywhere because it isn't on your PATH. Running `/home/crs/cool-retro-term/cool-retro-term` from the terminal or clicking the `.desktop` icon you added to the Dash should work however. If it does not please post the terminal output for the first command.

Comment: yes, like this it works, but i want to know if i can make a command like cool-retro-term so when i call it to run the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that your program resides in `/home/crs/cool-retro-term/` 
open `.bashrc` file by typing `gedit .bashrc` in terminal
scroll down to the last line, add new line and then paste this `PATH=$PATH:/home/crs/bin`
make a new file in gedit/terminal, add following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/crs/cool-retro-term/cool-retro-term
```

then save it in `/home/crs/bin` by whatever name you want.

make this file executable by `chmod u+x /home/crs/bin/<filename you just saved above>`

then run this file from terminal it should launch the program.
if you have any problem please comment.

Comment: /home/student/uso/tema1/year/cool-retro-term/cool-retro-term: /home/student/uso/tema1/year/cool-retro-term/cool-retro-term: cannot execute binary file
this is the error

Comment: This is wrong. The bash in front of /home/crs/cool-retro-term/cool-retro-term is what causes the error. Also the script is not needed if you would just put everthing from /home/crs/cool-retro-term/ in /home/crs/bin. That wouldn't clutter your home directory. Just follow my answer.

Comment: @user3582615 I have edited my answer. I made correction in bash script(please take a look to my answer again) by removing `bash` from `bash /home/crs/cool-retro-term/cool-retro-term`. you should now get error now.

Comment: yes it works. THanks . i have another question . if i want to run it with `sudo cool-retro-term` it says `the command not found`. if i run `sudo cool-retro-term/cool-retro-term` it is OK. how to make now to run just sudo cool-retro-term -h for example?

Comment: @user3582615 see when you added new PATH in .bashrc file all the commands in bin folder will be available for only crs user. when you use sudo you are becoming root user. for root user your bashrc file does not work ! for that you have to have to use full path ! i dont recommend you to modify profile file(similar to .bashrc file for you) for  root user !
besides when you will run that program by becoming root i.e. using sudo, the program will have settings different from when run without sudo.
hope it helps, if not pls comment.

Comment: @user3582615 if your problem is solved, please vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

Edit ~/.profile and put in:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Then move everything from /home/crs/cool-retro-term/ to /home/crs/bin

Now every time you put something in /home/crs/bin you can just execute it with the name of the file.

Comment: if i write ~/.profile in terminal it says Permision Denied

Comment: That is because just putting `~/.profile` in your terminal tries to run that file, but it isn't a program so it is not allowed to run. You need to edit that file with an editor. You can use nano in the terminal or gedit without a terminal to do that. Also note that those lines maybe are already in there. In that case you don't need to put it in twice, but you just continue with the steps after that.

Comment: still it does not run when i type cool-retro-term, i did like you said, i need to run another command to make it exectubale? or the modifiy the exec from cool-retro-term.desktop?

Comment: Somebody (wrongly..) edited my stuff to say "$HOME/crs/bin" please check again it looks like the above. Also could you execute `tree` while you are in /home/crs/bin for me please?

Comment: Just put in pastebin or something.

Comment: in that ~/.profile    it says # set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists

Comment: so is $HOME/bin or $HOME/crs/bin  ?

Comment: It's $HOME/bin. If it's already there, it's fine. Please post the output of the tree command inside /home/crs/bin somewhere.